# C# record types: how to localize automatically generated ToString method

Tags: c#, localization, record, c#-9.0

I am currently trying to familiarize myself with `record` types in C#9.
They are a handy new type for working with immutable data and come with some compiler-generated methods for things like equality comparisation and string representation.

For playing around, I created a simple class library and some unit-tests for that.
Everything works fine on PC "A", which is running Win10 in English.
But when I try to run my tests on PC "B", which has a german Win10 installed, some tests will fail.
The reason is, that the automatically generated `ToString` method will use the PC's default locale.

Now assume you have a very simple record:

```cs
public record SimpleRecordType(double Value);
```

And a test:

```cs
[Fact]
public void CreateStringRepresentation()
{
    var recordAsString = new SimpleRecordType(1.23).ToString();
    Assert.Equal("SimpleRecordType { Value = 1.23 }", recordAsString);
}
```

This test will fail on a german PC, because the string will look like this:
`SimpleRecordType { Value = 1,23 }`
(comma instead of decimal point)

I know that this test is quite pointless: I should just trust the compiler to properly generate the `ToString` method. But for learning and maybe for logging or other scenarios, I would like to have more control over the localization.

**Now to my question:**
Records are meant to be used with values, like my `double` up there.
So is there any easy way to change the used `CultureInfo` to `CultureInvariant` while keeping the benefit of the automatically generated `ToString` method?

As far as I can see, the compiler doesn't create an overload which takes arguments...

Comment: You might want to change your view on ToString. Its intention is not to be a conversion method but more or less a debugging feature to show the state of an object. Sometimes that looks like beeing the same but it isn't. If you need a consistent conversion between your type and a string or some other type write explicit conversion operations.

Comment: @Ralf, you are probably right. I didn't mean to use it as a substitute for serialization, but it would still be nice to have a consistent way to view the data...

Comment: If you're going to be comparing ToString'd values to strings in your test suite, it would make a lot of sense to ensure that your test suite is running in a known locale which isn't dependent on the machine running the test suite.

Comment: You can set `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` in your test suites

Comment: Note also that depending on the ToString'd output of e.g. a record or anonymous type is probably a bad idea. As far as I know the compiler doesn't give any guarantees as to the format of the string returned, and e.g. an empty string and `null` appear the same.

Comment: @canton7, thanks for the answer. But as I said in my post, it isn't really about the test itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the compiler isn't localising this - the compiler just calls `ToString()` on all members, and since `double.ToString()` is automatically localised, what you see is the outcome.

The record design intentionally doesn't provide any toggles to change how things are generated - the language design team felt this would be a bottomless pit. Instead they released SourceGenerators as part of the latest C# release. These can straightforwardly be used to generate a `ToString` method on records or generate `ToString(IFormatProvider)` overloads.

You would have to mark all records as `partial`. Then the SourceGenerator will detect all records and generate a file with a partial implementation of a record.

That partial implementation should define the following methods:

```cs
partial record MyRecord
{
    protected virtual bool PrintMembers(StringBuilder builder)
    {
        return PrintMembers(builder, null);
    }

    protected virtual bool PrintMembers(StringBuilder builder, IFormatProvider? formatProvider)
    {
        //code goes here
        return true; //return true if any members to print, false otherwise
    }
    
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ToString(null);
    }
    
    public virtual string ToString(IFormatProvider? formatProvider)
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.Append("MyRecord");
        stringBuilder.Append(" { ");
        if (PrintMembers(stringBuilder, formatProvider))
        {
            stringBuilder.Append(" ");
        }
        stringBuilder.Append("}");
        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```

For records that inherit from other records you will generate:

```cs
partial record SubRecord: MyRecord
{
    protected override bool PrintMembers(StringBuilder builder)
    {
        return PrintMembers(builder, null);
    }

    protected override bool PrintMembers(StringBuilder builder, IFormatProvider? formatProvider)
    {
        if (base.PrintMembers(builder, formatProvider))
        {
            builder.Append(", ");
        }
        //code goes here
        return true; //return true if any members to print, otherwise just directly return base.PrintMembers
    }
    
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ToString(null);
    }
    
    public override string ToString(IFormatProvider? formatProvider)
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.Append("SubRecord");
        stringBuilder.Append(" { ");
        if (PrintMembers(stringBuilder, formatProvider))
        {
            stringBuilder.Append(" ");
        }
        stringBuilder.Append("}");
        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Yair! I just had a (very) short look at the source generators you mentioned ([link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-c-source-generators/))
This seems to be the solution to my question, eventhough it is probably overkill for the example I gave ;-)

Comment: Ooof. I certainly appreciate the effort, but it is a bit more code than I had hoped for! The first clue might have bee enough for me, but I guess this will proof usefull some day ;-)

Comment: It is quite a bit of code, but is needed to make this robust in the face of inheritance - it's what the compiler currently generates. The good news is you don't need to write it yourself, and it's relatively straightforward to generate. I reckon I could do it in an hour or 2 if I had the motivation :-).